# Access token generated in SPA is not authenticated in web api(C#)

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal

I am using msal-angular for Azure aad authetntication. When I now call the web API (written in C#) I am getting unauthorized access 401.

**Expected behavior**:
Once the API is called with the token request should be successful and hit the web API.

**MSAL-angular version**: "@azure/msal-angular": "^0.1.2"

> Below is my app.module.ts

```
export const protectedResourceMap:[string, string[]][]=[ ['http://localhost:8133/api/FrameworkData/ReleaseManagement/GetAllFrameworkDetails/',['api://d6d2dc96-6757-47f7-83bd-2212e5e9099d/access_as_user']] ];

MsalModule.forRoot({
        clientID: 'b8b72473-3f78-4f5d-bf08-8a2e2a3d135e',//'6226576d-37e9-49eb-b201-ec1eeb0029b6',
        authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/26fa1297-1ee6-412a-a80a-cebf476ec6ad/",
        validateAuthority: true,
        redirectUri: "http://localhost:4200/",
        cacheLocation : "localStorage",
        //loadFrameTimeout:10000,
        postLogoutRedirectUri: "http://localhost:4200/",
        navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true,
        popUp: false,
        consentScopes: ["user.read", 'api://d6d2dc96-6757-47f7-83bd-2212e5e9099d/access_as_user'], //"api://a88bb933-319c-41b5-9f04-eff36d985612/access_as_user"
        unprotectedResources: ["https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/"],
        protectedResourceMap: protectedResourceMap,
        logger: loggerCallback,
        correlationId: '1234',
        level: LogLevel.Info,
        piiLoggingEnabled: true
      }
```

Actual issue- token is generated and it is sending in the request header as bearer.
GET http://localhost:8133/api/FrameworkData/ReleaseManagement/GetAllFrameworkDetails/ 401 (Unauthorized)

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: You requesting a token for msgraph when indicating the user.read on scope. Try to remove the user.read from consentScopes